# $\mathcal P(K)=\mathcal R(K)$ iff $\Bbb C\backslash K$ is connected

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, sp.spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $K$ be a compact set in $\Bbb C$. Let $\mathcal P(K)$ be the closed algebra generated by polynomials on $K$ and $\mathcal R(K)$ the closed algebra generated by rational functions without poles in $K$.

It is clear that $\mathcal P(K)\subset\mathcal R(K)$. If $\Bbb C\backslash K$ is a connected set, then [Runge's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge's_theorem) implies that $\mathcal P(K)=\mathcal R(K)$. The converse of this which is

> If $\Bbb C\backslash K$ is not connected, then $\mathcal P(K)\ne\mathcal R(K)$.

is apparently true, according to Graham Allan's Introduction to Banach Spaces and Algebras. How is it proved? Perhaps did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Nitpick: his first name was Graham, his last name was Allan

Comment: I didn't notice that, I think I'd better put the full name in. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is not an entirely satisfactory answer but I thought I would put it down as something to be improved later. (I don't remember the context in which GRA stated this fact, so perhaps he had in mind some argument based on nearby parts of the book.)

It is a theorem that in a unital Banach algebra $A$ the spectrum of $a\in A$ relative to the closed unital subalgebra ${\rm alg}(a)$ generated by $a$ is the polynomial hull of $\sigma_A(a)$. Now if $A=R(K)$ and $a(z)=z$, then $\sigma_A(a)=K$; I have a vague recollection that this requires a little work to prove, by first showing that the character space of $R(K)$ is $K$.

Anyway, $P(K)={\rm alg}(a)$. So if $P(K)=R(K)$ then $K$ must equal its own polynomial hull, and this is known to imply ${\bf C}\setminus K$ is connected.

Comment: There should be a more elementary proof along the following lines: assume that $K$ disconnects the plane, and pick $z_0$ in one of the bounded components of ${\bf C}\setminus K$, then play with the function $(z-z_0)^{-1}\in R(K)$ and use Cauchy's theorem in some way to show it cannot be approximated unif on $K$ by polynomials.

Comment: The statement in my question was given as a corollary of Runge's Theorem. I can see the if part but not the only if part, the preceding pages do not mention that either.

Comment: By the way, could you please give me the reference to the first sentence of your second paragraph? I don't think I've heard of that, or the word polynomial hull for that matters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure GRA states and proves the theorem in his book. (I haven't read the book but I did attend the lectures whose notes became the book.)

Comment: OK I'll try to find it then. Thank you.

Comment: @YemonChoi It is indeed possible to give a proof based on elementary complex analysis, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a more elementary proof is the following :

Assume $\mathbb{C} \setminus K$ is disconnected. Let $V$ be a bounded component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus K$, and let $w \in V$. Let us show that the function $g(z):= 1/(z-w) \in \mathcal{R}(K)$ does not belong to $\mathcal{P}(K)$. Assume for a contradiction that there are polynomials $(p_n)$ such that $p_n \to g$ uniformly on $K$. Then in particular $(z-w)p_n \to 1$ uniformly on $\partial V \subset K$, so that $(z-w)p_n \to 1$ uniformly on $V$, by the maximum modulus principle. This implies that $p_n \to g$ uniformly on compact subsets of $V \setminus \{w\}$.

Now, let $\gamma$ be a circle in $V \setminus \{w\}$ around $w$. Uniform convergence and Cauchy's theorem gives
$$0 = \int_\gamma p_n(z) dz \to \int_\gamma g(z) dz = 2\pi i,$$
a contradiction.

Comment: I had a feeling something like this would work but I was a bit worried about Jordan curve issues and domains with nasty boundary

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, so was I, until I realized these issues could be avoided thanks to the maximum modulus principle.

Comment: Ah, the maximum modulus principle. Very neat indeed, thank you very much.